# Ruby - Option within parameter

Tags: ruby

I am having trouble understand options with ruby.

```
def most_frequent_kmers(opt={})
   str            = opt[:str]
   min_chunk_size = opt[:min_chunk_size] || 1
   max_chunk_size = opt[:max_chunk_size] || str.length - 1
   min_occurences = opt[:min_occurences] || 1
   results        = {}
   top_scoring    = {}
end
most_frequent_kmers(1)
```

which gives me an error of

```
 `[]': no implicit conversion of Symbol into Integer (TypeError)
```

I am not sure what to do to solve this.

Comment: It's true that `3 || 2 - 1 #=> 3`, but readers of your code you appreciate  parentheses: `3 || (2 - 1)`. When you report an error in a SO question please indicate the line of code where it occurred as well as the message. Note that your method would never be written that way as `results` and `top_scoring` are both local variables that have no purpose and whose values are lost when the method is exited.

Answer (score 1):

you should pass instead to `most_frequent_kmers` a hash like that:

```
# depends on the ruby version you are using
# {str: "hey"} and {:str => "hey"} work also
most_frequent_kmers(str: "hey")
```

Answer (score 1):

`opts` means you can pass an "unlimited" number of arguments when calling the function, but all of them should be named, as you can see in the method's body:

```
str            = opt[:str]
min_chunk_size = opt[:min_chunk_size] || 1
max_chunk_size = opt[:max_chunk_size] || str.length - 1
min_occurences = opt[:min_occurences] || 1
...
```

It's assigning the value of the parameter str within the opt one, min_chunk_size, and so on. But in the case of str, this is the only one that doesn't have a "default" value, but even so, this way `max_chunk_size` depends on this, when that value as argument isn't provided (since the str.length - 1 assignment).

For making use `most_frequent_kmers` you need to provided a String object, as the str argument (really I think it should be a String, as per the name - str). So this way the logic inside is able to keep working, all other local variables in it have default values if they're not provided.

If you want to pass `str` as argument, you can just do `most_frequent_kmers(str: 'Some String')`, if you don't then it'll return a `NoMethodError`, since `opt[:str]` will be `nil`, and the "fallback" value for when that happens will try to invoke the `length` method on `nil`.

And tl;dr;, since you're just passing an Integer as argument, Ruby tries to invoke `[]` on the opts argument, raising the TypeError for trying an implicit conversion since [`Integer#[]`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.1/Integer.html#method-i-5B-5D) expects to receive an Integer as argument, and you're passing a symbol.